# Redundancy in Winston Logger

Tags: node.js, winston

As there is redundancy in the below code except the file name... Please suggest me ways to reduce it as I am very new to node js. How can I pass file name as an argument while calling the logger from my application.

```
const loggerForDWTApps = createLogger({
    level: loggerLevel === 'undefined' ? 'debug' : loggerLevel,
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        }),
        format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)),
    transports: [new transports.File({ filename: path.join(logDir, 'XYZ.log') })
    ]    
});

const loggerForDWTService = createLogger({
    level: loggerLevel === 'undefined' ? 'debug' : loggerLevel,
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        }),
        format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)),
    transports: [new transports.File({ filename: path.join(logDir, 'ABC.log') })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a function, say createLoggerWrapper that accepts any varying parameters for your logger configuration.

For example:

```
function createLoggerWrapper(logFile) {
  return createLogger({
    level: loggerLevel === 'undefined' ? 'debug' : loggerLevel,
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        }),
        format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)),
    transports: [new transports.File({ filename: path.join(logDir, logFile) })]
  });
}

const loggerForDWTApps = createLoggerWrapper('XYZ.log');
const loggerForDWTService = createLoggerWrapper('ABC.log');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function and call it as shown below :

```js
function getWinstonConfig(fileName) {
   return {
      level: loggerLevel === 'undefined' ? 'debug' : loggerLevel,
      format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        }),
        format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)),
        transports: [new transports.File({ filename: path.join(logDir, '${fileName}.log')})]    
   }
}
const loggerForDWTApps = createLogger(getWinstonConfig('ABC'));

const loggerForDWTService = createLogger(getWinstonConfig('XYZ'));
```